# Is there a way to hide the ellipses of the application buttons in the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar

When the application name is long, the application buttons in the taskbar are truncated and show an ellipsis at the end.

I often have multiple applications open and sometimes I feel that there are too many ellipses and if I could hide them I would be able to see more text.

Is this possible, or how can I do it? Thank you!

(The image below is how my taskbar looks like)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b0hl.png

Comment: Do you want to see ALL the text? Or an icon instead? If you want to see all the text, you'll need to make sure taskbar multi-line and have 2 rows of icons & text. Even with double-line, you'll get `...` after ~20 characters.

Comment: no, the ellipsis can't be removed, otherwise users can't know whether the title was truncated or not. You should resize the taskbar to make it higher

Comment: It looks like I can't just hide the ellipses, so I'll leave them there. Thank you both for your answers!